# Why does moveit depend on swig-wx?

Tags: moveit

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`swig-wx` is deprecated should `moveit` not depend on Qt instead?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/63238/why-does-moveit-depend-on-swig-wx?/) by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on ROS Answers with karma: 17335 on 2013-05-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It does not depend on swig-wx. The warning:

`WARNING: Package name "swig-wx" does not follow the naming conventions. It should start with a lower case letter and only contain lower case letters, digits and underscores.`

Will appear anywhere that rosdep is referenced if swig-wx is installed. The best fix is uninstall swig-wx and its upstream dependencies:

`sudo apt-get remove swig-wx`

Note: swig-wx is deprecated and will be removed in Hydro.

---

Originally posted by [Dave Coleman](https://answers.ros.org/users/1279/dave-coleman/) with karma: 1396 on 2013-05-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1